# Please don't be so trigger happy about closing questions

Tags: support, closed-questions, exact-duplicates, reopen-request

The ability to close questions as duplicates is great when used properly. However, I believe the community got a tad trigger happy with my question:

**My question**: [How to (re)enable the “New” context menu items for an administrator when right-clicking in a folder and selecting New > X?](https://superuser.com/questions/215360/how-to-reenable-the-new-context-menu-items-for-an-administrator-when-right-cl)

**Duplicate question**:[Can't create new folder from anywhere in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/76916/cant-create-new-folder-from-anywhere-in-windows-7)

Perhaps the moderators did not take the time to fully understand the difference between my question and the other question. The referenced question specifically states they are missing the "new" menu from their contextual menu which is quite different from my question that is missing the sub menu items under a specific circumstance.

Please re-open my question.

Comment: Ironically, the trigger scares me to heck.

Comment: if you have any other issues, feel free to come to the [Super User chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) to discuss them :-)

Comment: Once you have 250+ rep, you can see close votes on your own questions. If you see that your question has been nominated for closing, look at the rationale provided, and either a) edit your question to fix whatever is causing it to be closed, or b) post a comment stating why you think it shouldn't be closed. I will sometimes even comment on posts nominated for closing that aren't mine, stating why I think the question should remain open.

Comment: @nhinkle There never is any rationale for closing a question other than a standard remark that the question is not a real question, "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical " it doesn't matter if the closer thinks it is one of those things he just lists them all with no attempt at stating Where/why it is any of them. I was in such a situation and a comment on it asking for why got no response. I saw the "votes" you call them ? where two names appeared where it says it was closed. A different question to this one. The problem, is the fact that a closer can do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re-opened as of now.